# Wordpress any page named "Blog" is empty/blank when viewed

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, themes

Whether it's assigned as the recent posts page, or just a default template, whenever I name a page "Blog" with a permalink "mysite.com/blog", I get a blank page with absolutely nothing when viewing in a browser.  I am able to assign a blog page with a different permalink e.g. "mysite.com/blog1", it just can't be "Blog".  I've tried reverting to a default .htaccess as well as deactivating all plugins, I've also tried reinstalling the theme, Karma, and nothing works.  Any suggestions?  This is very odd behavior.

Comment: do you happen to have a folder called blog inside your WordPress installation directory?

Comment: That was it, it's not my server so I wasn't aware of it until your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior may be coming from one of your plugins. I had the same issue with a testimonial plugin which was messing things up with the permalink, "mysite.com/testimonials". If I'd name the page "recommendations", I didn't have that problem. It was only "testimonials" that gave me empty pages. So check your plugins.

Comment: All plugins are deactivated and I'm still getting a blank page for some reason